# How I can save each column of Dataframe to separated column in CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

when I save my dataframe to csv file, It is combined in one column, I want each column of data frame to appear in separated column in CSV file, this is the code

```
df.to_csv(r'myData.csv',sep=',',encoding="utf-8",columns=['id','created_at','text'])
```

but it is saved in one column of CSV file, in A column separated by comma

```
0,2019-09-28 08:58:13,"The TRUTH about Carbon Dioxide"
```

and I want each value in separated column A,B,C

Is there any way to do that? 
what I got is

[image]

what I want is:

[image]

thank you

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far? A snippet of your code/attempt will help users of StackOverflow help you.

Answer (score 3):

OK
the answer is simply changing `sep=','` to `sep=';'`

Answer (score 0):

In a csv file, each row is a separate line, and in this row, the different columns are separated by comma.

So

```
`0,2019-09-28 08:58:13,"The TRUTH about Carbon Dioxide"`
```

is a row of the data frame, not a column. The columns are still separated by comma in the csv file.

Comment: yes , I know that, I have to clarify what I mean by photos

Comment: You are reading the file in excel? I think excel has as default a delimiter different than `,`. You have to specify the delimiter manually. https://wiseflow.zendesk.com/hc/en-gb/articles/115000709394-How-to-open-a-CSV-file-in-Excel-PC-MAC-