# Pandas dataframe to excel into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

When I convert my pandas dataframe into a csv it all puts it in one column, I would like it to be in multiple columns.

this my code

```
df = pd.concat([data_2020, data_2019Q4, data_2019Q3, data_2019Q2, data_2019Q1, data_2018QH1, data_2017H1,
                data_2016H1, data_2015H1])

split_data = df["Date,Country,City,Specie,count,min,max,median,variance"].str.split(",")
data = split_data.to_list()
names = ['Date', 'Country', 'City', 'Specie', 'count', 'min', 'max', 'median', 'variance']
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=names)

new_df.to_csv('concat_data1.csv', sep=",",header=None,columns=names)
```

Edit :

Sample of my dataframe

```
               Date Country      City Specie count   min    max median variance
0        2020-02-02      RS  Novi Sad   pm10    48   4.0   42.0   14.0   742.70
1        2020-02-05      RS  Novi Sad   pm10    48   5.0   21.0    9.0   115.46
2        2020-02-24      RS  Novi Sad   pm10    48  10.0   99.0   27.0  3611.91
3        2020-03-02      RS  Novi Sad   pm10    41   3.0   68.0   14.0  1515.22
4        2020-05-09      RS  Novi Sad   pm10    36   9.0  102.0   15.0  5511.02
```

Comment: add your top 5 rows sample

Comment: just added it! @pyd

Comment: i am confused.  CSV is just a text file where "columns" are denotes by commas.  However, the CSV file itself is just strings on a line.  If you choose to open that CSV in Excel, the you can tell excel how to read those commas as delimiters or as all text in a cell per line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked by replacing the sep "," by ";"

Answer (score 0):

Could you use sth like `new_df.to_excel('concat_data.xlsx')`? This stores your df column-wise. However, this stores it as an Excel-file, not csv, so this solution only works for you if you are further processing/opening the data in Excel.

Comment: there are too many rows for it to fit in an excel file that's why I used to_csv

Comment: hm..ok. do you just need to save the dataframe somewhere for later use (in any format) or does it specifically have to be .csv?

Comment: it has to be .csv or .excel yes

Comment: Maybe this helps: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146464/how-i-can-save-each-column-of-dataframe-to-separated-column-in-csv-file)

Comment: thank you <3 it did actually work with replacing sep="," by sep=";". I don't why but cool